# How to define createdate of entire image folder using terminal with exiftool?

Tags: exiftool

I have folder containing images. I have to rename them according to their date n all. But when I used

```
$ exiftool '-filename<CreateDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le -r /home/ubuntu/house
Warning: No writable tags set from /home/ubuntu/house/120151116163735582.jpg
```

And when i used

```
$ exiftool '-FileName<${CreateDate}_${Exif:Model}.jpg' -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S-%%2c *  
Warning: [minor] Tag 'CreateDate' not defined - 120151116163715535.jpg
Warning: No writable tags set from 120151116163715535.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Files with the warning

```
Warning: No writable tags set from /home/ubuntu/house/120151116163735582.jpg
```

don't have a tag `CreateDate`. For this reason, the files can not be renamed.

---

To illustrate this:

```
% exiftool '-filename<CreateDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le  ~/tmp
Warning: No writable tags set from /home/aboettger/tmp/relax.jpg
    1 directories scanned
    0 image files updated
    1 image files unchanged


% exiftool -CreateDate ~/tmp   
======== /home/aboettger/tmp/relax.jpg
    1 directories scanned
    1 image files read

% exiftool -CreateDate="2011:11:25 12:00:00" ~/tmp
Warning: Duplicate Orientation tag in IFD0 - /home/aboettger/tmp/relax.jpg
    1 directories scanned
    1 image files updated

% exiftool -createdate ~/tmp                      
======== /home/aboettger/tmp/relax.jpg
Create Date                     : 2011:11:25 12:00:00
    1 directories scanned
    1 image files read

% exiftool '-filename<CreateDate' -d %y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le  ~/tmp
    1 directories scanned
    1 image files updated

% ls -log ~/tmp 
total 56
-rw-rw-r-- 1 16501 Nov 25 10:04 111125_120000.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1  16473 Nov 25 09:55 relax.jpg_original
```

Comment: can u explain what you did sir? I'm new in this. And sir I have full folder where the images are going to upload on daily bases. How ill i give them CReateDate to all each n every time? @A.B.

Comment: What is the output of `exiftool -createdate /home/ubuntu/house/120151116163735582.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

As @A.B. said, the files don't have a CreateDate.  If these files are from a camera, then the tag you probably want to use instead is DateTimeOriginal, which is set by nearly all cameras.

Try this command:
`exiftool -time:all --system:all -s`
This will show you all the time tags (but not the file system timestamps) in your file and from there you can figure out what is the best tag to use for your command.